# How do I convert matrix columns into separate columns using dplyr?

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr

How do you "`unnest`" `matrix` columns in `dplyr`?

For example, what could I do with the `y` column to split it into 2 separate columns?

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:2)
df$y <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easiest option is `do.call` with `data.frame`

```
df1 <- do.call(data.frame, df)
str(df1)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x  : int  1 2
# $ y.1: int  1 2
# $ y.2: int  3 4
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, we can split the 'y' to a `list` column and then use `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(y = asplit(y, 2)) %>% 
    unnest_wider(c(y))
```